# Find recursively the original Id from data in one table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

First look at simple data and expected result that I want to achieve:

SAMPLE DATA

```
Id          ParentId    Mode
----------- ----------- ---------
28          0           A
29          30          B
30          0           R
31          32          C
32          33          T
33          34          Y
34          0           G
```

I can get my expected results using this query:

```
select 
    t1.Id,
    coalesce(t5.Id,t4.Id,t3.Id,t2.Id,t1.Id) as BaseId,
    coalesce(t5.Mode,t4.Mode,t3.Mode,t2.Mode,t1.Mode) as BaseMode
from
    #Table t1
left join 
    #Table t2 on t2.ParentId = t1.Id
left join 
    #Table t3 on t3.ParentId = t2.Id
left join 
    #Table t4 on t4.ParentId = t3.Id
left join 
    #Table t5 on t5.ParentId = t4.Id
```

Expected result:

```
Id          BaseId      BaseMode
----------- ----------- ---------
28          28          A
29          29          B
30          29          B
31          31          C
32          31          C
33          31          C
34          31          C
```

But the problem is - I don't know how many times I will have to left join..
I could be any number.

I tried to use recursive cte - but it blows my mind. And I see a problem to figure it out. Can anyone show me how to achieve it?

Here are simple data to paste in your management studio:

```
select * 
into #Table
from (select 28 as Id, 0 as ParentId, 'A' as Mode
union all select 29, 30, 'B'
union all select 30, 0, 'R'
union all select 31, 32, 'C'
union all select 32, 33, 'T'
union all select 33, 34, 'Y'
union all select 34, 0, 'G') data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
WITH ParentIdCTE (Id, BaseId, BaseMode, RecursionLevel)  
AS  
(  
SELECT 
    Id, 
    Id, 
    Mode,
    0 As RecursionLevel
FROM 
    #Table 

UNION ALL  

SELECT  
    p.Id, 
    e.Id, 
    e.Mode,
    p.RecursionLevel + 1  
FROM 
    ParentIdCTE As p        
INNER JOIN      
    #Table AS e      
ON 
    e.ParentId = p.BaseId  
WHERE
    p.BaseId <> 0 
    AND p.RecursionLevel < 10
)  
SELECT
    Id, 
    BaseId, 
    BaseMode
FROM
    ParentIdCTE 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        Id As MaxRecId,
        MAX(RecursionLevel) as MaxRecLevel
    FROM 
        ParentIdCTE AS s
    GROUP BY
        Id
) AS MaxRec
ON
    MaxRecId = Id
    AND MaxRecLevel = RecursionLevel
```

Of course, it can be improved in many ways. It's just an example. There's a limit to the recursion level, just to have a stronger query.

Comment: ParentIdCTE is used twice - could be problematic in sql-server especially if my Table is  quite large. But because of ID are always rising - so i can just group by Id, take min(BaseId)  and then do left join with Table insted of cte.
Anyway... THANKS A LOT - IT WORKS PERFECT FOR ME

Comment: Yes, you are right! But there are many solutions to the "greatest N per group" problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group). The example can be improved and I'm happy you solved in your specific scenario!